# Routing to multiple view models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, url-routing, sammy.js

I am working on a Knockout application using Sammy.js for the routing. So far, everything seems to be working, but before I continue with it, I want to make sure I am not doing anything wrong that can possibly cause any issues. My routing is below:

```
Sammy(function() {
    this.get('/admin/course#/', function() {
        ko.cleanNode($('body'));
        ko.applyBindings(CourseViewModel);
    });
    this.get('/admin/user#/', function() {
        ko.cleanNode($('body'));
        ko.applyBindings(UserViewModel);
    });

    this.get('/admin/user', function() { this.app.runRoute('get', '/admin/user#/'); });
    this.get('/admin/course', function() { this.app.runRoute('get', '/admin/course#/'); });
    this.get('', function() {});
    this.disable_push_state = true;
}).run();
```

Basically, when the page changes, the Sammy unbinds and view models and then binds a new view model. It seems to work so far. Is there a better method for doing this? Will it cause any issues?

I feel like using a bunch of view models as opposed to one large view model with make the code a lot more manageable so that is what I was looking to do.

Comment: I think cleaning node and applyBinding new viewmodel again and again is not efficient instead you should swap-in/swap-out the template according to data.
see this https://gist.github.com/kim3er/3478709

Comment: The problem with that is everything is in one view model. I have multiple database items (users, courses) that will have their own pages. Each page has the ability to query/add/edit/delete content. I was hoping to have view models for each function of the pages.

Comment: then you can try DurandalJs.

Comment: I suggest using knockout external template engine (https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/31/using-external-templates-knockout-js/) + simple div on your main page: `<div data-bind="template: { name: 'pages/' + page().id, data: page().model }">`. Thus changing page() observable, your template would be loaded from server and automatically binded with `page().model`.